# Summarise over all columns

Tags: r, dplyr, summarization

I have data of the following format:

```
gen = function () sample.int(10, replace = TRUE)
x = data.frame(A = gen(), C = gen(), G = gen(), T = gen())
```

I would now like to attach, to each row, the total sum of all the elements in the row (my actual function is more complex but `sum` illustrates the problem).

Without dplyr, I’d write

```
cbind(x, Sum = apply(x, 1, sum))
```

Resulting in:

```
   A C  G T Sum
1  3 1  6 9  19
2  3 4  3 3  13
3  3 1 10 5  19
4  7 2  1 6  16
…
```

But it seems surprisingly hard to do this with dplyr.

I’ve tried

```
x %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Sum = sum(A : T))
```

But the result is not the sum of the columns of each row, it’s something unexpected and (to me) inexplicable.

I’ve also tried

```
x %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Sum = sum(.))
```

But here, `.` is simply a placeholder for the *whole* `x`. Providing *no* argument does, unsurprisingly, also not work (results are all `0`). Needless to say, none of these variants works without `rowwise()`, either.

(There isn’t really any reason to necessarily do this in dplyr, but (a) I’d like to keep my code as uniform as possible, and jumping between different APIs doesn’t help; and (b) I’m hoping to one day get automatic and free parallelisation of such commands in dplyr.)

Comment: If sum is just for illustration it's perhaps a bad choice because there is a special function for that, as shown in the answer below. For other functions it might be more dplyr-like to gather your columns of interest, compute the values you are interested in and then spread (using for example tidyr). That's my interpretation at least..

Comment: I'm wondering if some like this `library(data.table) ; setDT(x)[, Sum := Reduce("+", .SD)][]` would be of any use...

Comment: @DavidArenburg, nice approach which works the same way with dplyr. How would you use it with a different function, for example the one from my answer? (I think the difference is that `+` is a binary function taking 2 inputs which can then be applied / reduced multiple times while `f` from my answer takes a whole vector at once..)

Comment: @docendodiscimus, this is why I've posted this in comments. We don't have Konrads real function so it may will be that it will work with `Reduce` too. Will wait and see what he says.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, sure - would certainly be interesting to know a bit more about the function input/output design.

Comment: @David I wanted to have a general solution, since this problem crops up for me again and again, with different functions. In my current case, the function isn’t amenable to `Reduce` – it calculates the GC bias from a frequency table of codons. Here’s an implementation: https://gist.github.com/klmr/4898c3eb1a5216850134

Answer (score 5):

I once did something similar, and by that time I ended up with:

```
x %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(data.frame(., res = sum(unlist(.))))
#    A  C G  T res
# 1  3  2 8  6  19
# 2  6  1 7 10  24
# 3  4  8 6  7  25
# 4  6  4 7  8  25
# 5  6 10 7  2  25
# 6  7  1 2  2  12
# 7  5  4 8  5  22
# 8  9  2 3  2  16
# 9  3  4 7  6  20
# 10 7  5 3  9  24
```

---

Perhaps your more complex function works fine without `unlist`, but it seems like it is necessary for `sum`. Because `.` refers to the "current group", I initially thought that `.` for e.g. the first row in the `rowwise` machinery would correspond to `x[1, ]`, which is a list, which `sum` swallows happily outside `do`

```
is.list((x[1, ]))
# [1] TRUE

sum(x[1, ])
# [1] 19
```

However, without `unlist` in `do` an error is generated, and I am not sure why:

```
x %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(data.frame(., res = sum(.)))
# Error in sum(.) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

Comment: Nice and more succinct approach! (+1) OTOH I think calling `do` and `data.frame` for each row might also be costly (perhaps it would be slightly more efficient with `data_frame`?)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! For my original use I didn't need to count microseconds, it was enough that it eventually worked... Yes, I have tried `data_frame`, but it doesn't return the desired result.

Comment: Huh. This works. So `.` is something for `do` (= the current group/row) than for `mutate` (= the whole table). Amazing. In my case, I also don’t need the `unlist`, but then, my function also accepts a one-row data.frame so that’s probably why. And yes, it’s quite slow in my case, but so is the `apply` approach, and [my actual function](https://gist.github.com/klmr/4898c3eb1a5216850134) is simply hellishly inefficient and not at all optimised.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have tried to find an official text on the use of `.`, in addition to what's written in `?do` and `?rowwise`. Perhaps the comment by @hadley [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23146616/dplyr-0-1-3-0-99-piping-the-pronoun-dot) ("The pronoun is supplied by either %>% or do() so it won't with arbitrary dplyr functions.") suggests that `.` is most happy together with `do`? Quite a lot is happening between versions though, so I am not sure about the current status of the friend and foes of `.`

Answer (score 3):

Does this do what you'd like?

```
Data %>%
   mutate(SumVar=rowSums(.))
```

Comment: It probably does but the actual function I’m using isn’t vectorised.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to show an example of what I wrote in my comment. Let's assume you have a custom-function `f`:

```
f <- function(vec) sum(vec)^2
```

And you want to apply this function to each row of your data.frame x. One option in base R would be to use `apply`, as you show in your question:

```
> transform(x, z = apply(x, 1, f))
#   A  C  G T   z
#1  5  7 10 7 841
#2  1  9  5 9 576
#3  7 10  2 4 529
#4  1  4 10 1 256
#5  4  4  5 2 225
#6  9  1  6 8 576
#7  9  3  7 1 400
#8  5  2  7 5 361
#9  6  3 10 4 529
#10 5 10  1 6 484
```

Little disadvantage here is, because you are using `apply` on a data.frame, the whole data.frame is converted to `matrix` first and this would mean of course that all columns are converted to the same type.

With dplyr (and tidyr) you could solve the problem with gathering/melting and spreading/casting afterwards.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
x %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>%    # add row numbers for grouping 
  gather(key, value, A:T) %>%
  group_by(n) %>% 
  mutate(z = f(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  select(-n)

#Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
#
#     z A  C  G T
#1  841 5  7 10 7
#2  576 1  9  5 9
#3  529 7 10  2 4
#4  256 1  4 10 1
#5  225 4  4  5 2
#6  576 9  1  6 8
#7  400 9  3  7 1
#8  361 5  2  7 5
#9  529 6  3 10 4
#10 484 5 10  1 6
```

This is obviously quite a bit longer code than using `apply` but as soon as the data get a bit larger, I expect this to be a lot faster than any `apply` over the rows of a data.frame.

Alternatively, you could use `rowwise` if you specify the columns manually:

```
x %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(z = f(c(A,C,G,T)))  # manual column specification

#Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
#Groups: <by row>
# 
#  A  C  G T   z
#1  5  7 10 7 841
#2  1  9  5 9 576
#3  7 10  2 4 529
#4  1  4 10 1 256
#5  4  4  5 2 225
#6  9  1  6 8 576
#7  9  3  7 1 400
#8  5  2  7 5 361
#9  6  3 10 4 529
#10 5 10  1 6 484
```

I haven't figured out yet, if the `rowwise` solution can be changed so that it would work with character input of the column names - perhaps with lazyeval somehow.

#### data:

```
set.seed(16457)
gen = function () sample.int(10, replace = TRUE)
x = data.frame(A = gen(), C = gen(), G = gen(), T = gen())
```

Comment: To be honest, the melting solution looks incredibly inefficient: Melting and spreading doesn’t come free, it involves a lot of (in this case) gratuitous copying. Manually specifying the columns isn’t feasible in my case either, since my actual data has 61 columns, not four (well, I could obviously use `mutate_` to work around that). I get the impression that this is a missing verb in dplyr … that said, thanks for this thorough answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, You are right about the efficiency concerns (I made a small benchmark). Perhaps someone will come up with a cleaner and more efficient alternative - I'll also be interested in learning that