# Unable to use sum function inside dplyr::mutate

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new variable that, for each row, sums the values of previous variables. Generically:

```
dataset %>%
select(var1, var2, var3) %>%
mutate(var4 = sum(var1:var3))
```

I get the error "numerical expression has x elements: only the first used", where x is the number of observations in the dataset. Initially I thought the error was related to the size of my dataset, which contains observations in the low thousands. But I get the same error when I adapted the above code to the built-in mtcars dataset. I also verified that all the values of the variables I want to sum are of class / mode numeric, and that there are no NAs. I appreciate any insight.

Comment: Try `rowSums(var1:var3)` maybe? Or actually `sum(.)` for this calculation

Comment: @RichardScriven, I think it's not possible to use this colon notation inside rowSums, is it? You could do something like `mtcars %>% mutate(x = rowSums(.[1:3]))` or `rowwise` and `sum`

Comment: @docendodiscimus You're right.  It's not.  zhaoy, you  want to use to use al the numeric columns, so perhaps a logical column subset is more appropriate.  You definitely won't remember all the names for a 100 column data set

Comment: See also this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095526/summarise-over-all-columns and another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354734/dplyr-mutate-rowsums-calculations-or-custom-functions